# Getting number of elements from user input?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, scanning

I've been googling this but I still don't understand why this doesn't work. The user would enter an array of integers and I need to find how many elements are in that array.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = 0; //# of elements in list
while(s.hasNextInt()) {
    n++;
    s.next();           
} 
System.out.println(n);
```

I looked up if using variable outside the scope works, and I've been answers saying that if you're gonna use the variable outside the scope, you should declare and initialize outside the scope (in this case, the while loop). However, this still doesn't work for me. My code right now won't even print "0". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you read from command line you have to signal EOF (end of file), otherwise how will your program know if you have stopped entering your elements or not? On windows you can press Ctrl-D and your scanner will stop reading, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think I have an idea of where to go now. I'm thinking of using hasNextLine(). Right now what I have is while(s.hasNextInt() && ! s.hasNextLine()), but the condition didn't pass so my n remained as 0. Do you have any suggestions as to how to go about implementing this? (if it will work that is)

Comment: @xerop no, this is weird. What are you trying to achieve? Do you understand what I said at all? Since you are reading from command line and not from a file, you have to explicitly tell your java program to stop reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can break out of the loop with the condition that a word is entered, such as "exit" since you want to get an int count. Your code works to count the number of integers entered into a scanner, but you never declared an array to hold all the values.

```
 package com.company;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList array = new ArrayList(); //declare your array


    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0; //# of elements in list
    while(s.hasNextInt())
    {
        n++;
        s.next();
        array.add(s);//store the array value

        if (s.hasNext("exit"))//allow an exit to the loop
            break;

    }
    System.out.println(array.size()); //better, use the size of the array

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.
Check this link. https://ideone.com/vrnoEz

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n = 0; //# of elements in list
         while(s.hasNextInt()) {
         n++;
         s.next();           
     } 
    System.out.println(n);
   }
}
```

Comment: your code has a mistake.because you never declared the array to hold the input values.

Comment: The question was to find the number of elements present.